# How to send data from an R package to a Quarto document

Tags: r, package, quarto

Here is a very simple function in an R package named Demo:

```
#' DemoQuarto
#'
#' @return text123
#' @export text123
#'

hello <- function() {
  text123 <- print("Hello, world!")
}

usethis::use_template(
  template = QuartoDemo.qmd,
  save_as = example,
  data = list(Package = "Demo"),
  package = "Demo"
  )
```

The R package has a folder named templates, and there is a Quarto document inside called QuartoDemo.qmd

The Quarto document has a simple code chunk:

```
print(text123)
```

However, when I use the check() function from devtools, it returns this error:

```
! object 'QuartoDemo.qmd' not found
```

That seems odd, because QuartoDemo is in the /templates folder.

What are the steps to call a Quarto document using data from a function in an R package?

Comment: Did you try with quotes? `template = "QuartoDemo.qmd"`, otherwise `use_template()`  will look for object `QuartoDemo.qmd` as error states.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is helpful.

I changed the code to this:

usethis::use_template(
  template = "QuartoDemo.qmd",
  save_as = example.docx,
data = list(Package = "QuartoDemo"),
  open = TRUE
)

And it's returning these error messages:

Error : Could not find template 'QuartoDemo.qmd' in package 'usethis'.
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘QuartoDemo’

Very strange, as QuartoDemo.qmd is not in usethis.